Decrypting an ec encoded text with a public key
Can someone please help me finding a way to decrypt a text encrypted with an EC private key?
What I am trying to do is I am trying to understand how SSL certificates are structured and signed.
For that I am trying to see on a real world example what part of a certificate is encrypted. The most straightforward way to do it as it seems is to take a signature and decrypt it. But I failed to find any straightforward documentation on that part. Most of it refers only to symmetric encryption. Even ai assistants are not very helpful as they persist with verification tools, and i don't want a verification. I want to decrypt a message.
What am I doing wrong?

No part of a certificate is encrypted, and while RSA signatures can incorrectly be (and in some, espeically older, libs/tools/etc are) treated as sort-of-almost-partly-like-backwards-encryption, ECDSA (and EdDSA) signatures cannot -- there is nothing in the signature that can be 'reversed' in any way, it can ONLY be verified using the signed data  or hash, or for non-ph Ed only the data. This is not really programming or development, and there are dozens of As on crypto.SX and security.SX about signatures not being encrypted.

The standard literally says "The signatureValue field contains a digital signature computed upon the ASN.1 DER encoded tbsCertificate".

And if you compute a signature from some data with a private key, which can be later computed back by a public key, what is it if not an encryption/decryption?

Ok it seems like I have misunderstood the concept of signature verification and it really depends on a signature algorithm. In the case of ECDSA the verification process is described here
https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/private/x9-62-09-20-98.pdf
and it does not seem to contain any reproduction of encrypted message. Instead there is some math involved to check the properties of the signature with a public key and the original, believed to be signed, message.
